# Object array copy constructor

Tags: c++

I have an object PointArray with a field Point *array. I want to make a copy constructor:

```
PointArray::PointArray(const PointArray &pv) {
    size = pv.size;
    array = new Point[size];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        Point toAdd = Point(pv.array[i].getX(), pv.array[i].getY());
        array[i] = toAdd;
    }
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector` and a lot of these problems just go away. You won't even need a separate `size` property.

Comment: Why don't you directly assign to `array[i]`?

Comment: Tip: Use constructor lists where possible, as in `PointArray::PointArray(...) : size(pv.size) { ... }`

Comment: If I directly assign, won't that make array[i] have the same reference to pv.array[i]?

Comment: It can't. That's not an array of references. It will make copies. In C++ references don't happen implicitly, they must be expressed somehow in the type definition.

Comment: is this the same case as in Java? I could have sworn I've heard if you have obj1 = obj2 then obj1 is a reference to obj2 (any change to obj2 reflects on obj1) in Java

Comment: As much as Java is heavily inspired by C++, C++ is not Java. This *will* be a copy operation, no questions. In Java object references can be passed around like that and you must make an explicit copy. Not so in C++ where this will be implicitly copied.

Comment: ok so if I do obj1 = obj2 in C++, it will copy all the fields of obj2?

Comment: It will *call the copy constructor* if one is defined, or the automatically generated copy constructor if no such constructor was specified.

Comment: In any case, do look into `std::vector` as it can save you a whole world of hurt. I do mean *world* as C++ has an infinite capacity for inflicting pain and suffering if you remain ignorant about some of the more esoteric aspects of memory management and the [RIAA principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). Try to avoid manual allocation with `new` or `new[]` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correct?

It depends.

How is the copy constructor that you designed supposed to behave? How does your constructor behave? Does it behave as you intended? What are the invariants of your class? Are those invariants maintained as the post condition of the constructor?

---

Some issues:

- Are you sure that the loop which copies the elements will never throw? Because if it throws, then the constructor leaks memory. In other words, it is not exception safe.
- The loop appears pointlessly complex. There is a standard algorithm for copying from a range: `std::copy`.
- Bare owning pointers and allocating `new` are not recommended.
- You seem to be pointlessly re-implementing a limited version of `std::vector`.